# Como están comparando la sigiuente metáfora: "Su luna de pergamino / preciosa tocando viene"

Tags: literatura, metáfora

Necesito saber como estan comparando la metáfora porfa  vor, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Son versos de Federico García Lorca; "**luna de pergamino**" es metáfora de **pandereta**, pues **la comparación esta basada en la forma circular que tiene la luna y la pandereta**. También puede ser un pandero, que es igual que la pandereta pero algo más grande.

La niña camina tocando una "**luna de pergamino**". Lorca nombra de esta manera al instrumento del **pandero** o **la pandereta** por su forma redondeada, su color blanco y porque está realizado de papel o piel de cuero de alguna res de ganado, lisa y estirada.